# I've been DDOS can I remove the trafic from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ddos

In the past few days my site have been ddos.
I mess up all my google analytics result. Is there a way to remove the trafic from the ddos attack from my google analytics.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the data once it's been collected in your view. You're best bet at this point is to create a custom segment that filters out the DDOS traffic and use that (instead of All Sessions) when viewing your reports.